# Memory overwrite when using strong and weak symbols in two linked files

Tags: gcc, memory, linker

Assume we have a 64-bit x86 machine, which is little-endian and therefore stores the least-significant byte of a word in the byte with the lowest address.
Assuming standard alignment rules for a 64-bit x86 Linux C compiler.

Consider

*File 1:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct cs {
    int count;
    unsigned short flags;
};
struct cs gcount;
extern void add_counter( int n );

int main(int c, char *argv[]);

int main(int c, char *argv[]) {
    gcount.flags = 0xe700;
    gcount.count = 1;
    add_counter(42);
    printf("count =%d\n", gcount.count);
    return 0;
}
```

*File 2:*

```
struct cs {
    unsigned short flags;
    int count;
};

struct cs gcount = {0,0};

void add_counter (int n) {
    gcount.count +=n;
}
```

If compiled the output is `1`.

*Explanation:*

> count is defined as a strong global int the second file is thus
>   initialized to {0,0}, here the order doesn't matter yet since it's
>   just all zeroes.
>
> A struct / type is defined per compilation unit so the first file uses
>   the first definition to write to the struct meaning
>
> gcount.flags = 0xe700; gcount.count=1;
>
> cause the memory to look like
>
> [e7 00 | 00 00 00 01] where (in little endian) the left is the top and
>   the right is the bottom of memory.
>
> (there's no padding between the two fields since short is at the end,
>   sizeof will report 8B though)
>
> when calling add_counter(42), the second file will use the second
>   definition of cs and look at the memory as
>
> [e7 00 00 00 | 00 01]
>
> Now there's a 2B padding in between the two fields and the write
>   access to the count will thus affect the range
>
> [*e7 00* 00 00 | 00 01]
>
> 42 is 0x2a in hexadecimal (2*16 + 10) and will thus result in
>
> [*e7 2a* 00 00 | 00 01]
>
> converting this back to the view the first file has we get
>
> [e7 2a | 00 00 00 01]
>
> and thus the result is 1 instead of the expected 43.

Now I do get the general gist but I'm a bit confused about why we get `[*e7 2a* 00 00 | 00 01]` when adding `42=0x2a` and not `[*e7 00 00 2a | 00 01]`.

I'm expecting `[*e7 00 00 2a | 00 01]` because we are using little-endian, meaning, the most right bit is the LSB. So `e7` would actualy represent the most significant 8 bits here.

Comment: The two source files in your program declare the external identifier `gcount` incompatibly, and both access it.  The resulting program therefore has undefined behavior.  There is very little utility in probing particular manifestations of undefined behavior in particular C language implementations.  Certainly the language standard does not give you any basis for having any expectation at all about what your program will do.

Comment: Also, get a better book.  Aside from the pseudo-explanation you've quoted being useless per my previous comment, and implementation-specific even if you choose to disregard that, it is overall using nonstandard terminology.  C has no sense of "strong" or "weak" symbols.  Although that concept does apply to some object file formats to which C programs are sometimes compiled, those terms have different meaning in that context than is being used in the "explanation".

Comment: Also also, byte-ordering has nothing to do with the relative order of structure members in memory.  They are required to be laid out in the order declared, and the explanation's description of how the bytes of the structure are laid out in memory is inconsistent with that.  Really, if this is typical of the book you're using then it cannot possibly be very hard to find a better one.

Comment: It might not be defined in the C-Standard (which I knew), it is nevertheless something one should have in mind and thus a topic one should cover.

Comment: One should know about byte ordering and structure layout, but it is of little use to teach specifics of what *might* happen if you do something you're not supposed to do.

Comment: Does this link? Two files define the same global variable. It looks strange.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana It does link because on is weak and the other is strong. The weak kind of introduces the name and the other kind of gives it an value - stupidly speaking. The linker doesn't care, the name is the same, the value is only given once, so he's happy. It can get even stranger since the linker doesn't care about the type. So you could make two files, one defines int x; and the other double x = 2; and you would get some crazy output.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Such exercises are actually quit beneficial. But I now get you problem, I forgot to add some details. Somehow they got lost, sorry! I'll add it.

Comment: I see this is a GCC specific thing. Maybe it should be tagged as such. This doesn't link in Visual Studio, nor in my version of LCC or Pelles C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My disparaging comments about the exercise itself notwithstanding, it is possible to interpret the question as a simpler one about byte ordering.  In that sense, the issue is with this assertion:

> little-endian, meaning, the most right bit is the LSB.

Little-endian means that the bytes are ordered from least significant to most significant.  The term having been coined in English and English being written left-to-right, that means the most *left* byte is the LSB in little-endian ordering.

Comment: i actually forgot to add some details. I updated my question.